# Supports opening documents in place in Xcode 13.0+

Tags: swift, xcode

In Xcode 12.0* for given access to user to see files in device used or created with app, I just did "Supports opening documents in place" -> Yes in info.plist also "Application supports iTunes file sharing" -> Yes, I am using same method for Xcode 13.0* However I cannot see the file or the folder of my app in Files, the approach I chose was Info tab in Targets and doing those modification. Do we need new thing in Xcode 13?

Comment: Make sure to test it on a real device. Also make sure to have at least one document saved in your document directory. As shown in the duplicate link you can just set Supports Document Browser to yes in your app Targets > Info > Custom iOS Target Properties

Comment: @LeoDabus: Yes, in real device works, but why `Supports Document Browser`? As long as I remember and also I had experience about it, we would need just `Supports opening documents in place` and `Application supports iTunes file sharing`. Also I did not use `Supports Document Browser` in testing on real iphone and it just worked.

Comment: I don’t know. I have always used Supports Document Browser. Didn’t even know that other approach used to work until a few days ago. Anyway glad it helped you solve your issue.

Comment: Thanks Leo, for help.